# Discord (app) and Discord.py appear to have different 'mention' criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a bot and trying make a function that will check if a string is a mention of a valid server user.

```
def validUser(string):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for user in guild.members:
            if user.mention == string:
                return True
    return False
```

When I added some print statements to find out why it wasn't working, I realized something quite strange. When you take a mention from a message in the app, it takes the form '<@![id]>'. However, when you use user.mention, it does '<@[id]>'. Both work when typed manually into discord, but they are obviously not compatible in my function. There are other ways to still make this function work, of course, but now I'm quite interested as to why this happens and if there is a way to make it...not happen.

Comment: What is `string` can you give an example of how are you getting it? consider reading [Message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.Message.mentions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now I'm quite interested as to why this happens

The [`Discord docs`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-formats) hold the answer. It depends on whether you mention a user by their username or their server nickname.

```
User                <@USER_ID>
User (Nickname)     <@!USER_ID>
```

If you want to get around this you could use a `regex` that allows an extra `!`. Depending on your use case, you can use a `Converter` (for command arguments) or have a look in `Message.mentions`.